# Does copy field requires data re-upload

Tags: solr

I have solr instance having lacks of data uploaded. I want to create a new copyfield which is concatenation of existing two fields.

Do I need to repopulate my data?

Comment: yes ...if you want to use the new copy field with earlier data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. From the [solr documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields)

> Fields are copied before **analysis** is done

By analysis in copyfield context they mean index analizer, which executed when a document is indexed.